# How to get Docker Compose/Docker Swarm/Kubernetes Container Number

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm

All container orchestrators like Docker Compose/Docker Swarm/Kubernetes provide a way to set the number of containers to run. While running inside one of these containers, is it possible to determine the number of the container e.g. 5 of 10 where the number I'm looking for is 5. Is this exposed as an environment variable or is there another way to get this number?

Comment: Each orchestrator is going to do this differently. I think it would be more appropriate to post a question per tool since the people that know each tool may be very different.

Comment: In a Kubernetes Deployment specifically, the individual Pods get somewhat arbitrary 5-character IDs, and if you also have a HorizontalPodAutoscaler configured or are doing a deployment or ... then the number of pods will be variable.

Comment: a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) has deterministic Pod naming although in the "5 of 10" part, the "of 10" will require digging into the `{spec: {replicas:}}` to know how many "of" are currently scheduled

Comment: I'm not sure this number would actually make any sense as pods are expected to get added/removed/replaced all the time and the numbers would get jumbled up in a hurry.  mdaniel's note about `StatefulSet` does give consistent numbers, but this deployment method means you can't do things like rolling updates.

Comment: @BMitch I wondered if there was a common method of deriving the container sequence number.

Comment: @tadman If you had pod 1, 2, 3 and 1 dies we are left with 2, 3. A new pod will replace it with number 1.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed There is no common method across these very different tools, which is why answers being provided are all tool specific.

Comment: That's a trivial example. What if you lose a node and 2, 3, 4, and 5 are dead. How do you know what the replacement numbers are? Only `StatefulSet` will figure this out for you, but as I said, huge drawbacks to that approach.

Answer (score 0):

In kubernetes you can get container names using jsonpath

```
containernames=$(kubectl  -n kube-system get pod <replacepodname> -o jsonpath={.spec.containers[*].name})
```

Then you can read the names one by one

echo $containernames | awk '{print $1 }'
echo $containernames | awk '{print $2 }'

or

set -- $containernames
echo $1
echo $2

Comment: This really doesn't help with numbering.

Comment: To my understanding kubernetes doesn't provide numbering of containers within pod. You have to manipulate by using json output of kubectl describe pod.

Comment: What output does this produce? Does it yield numbers?